# How can one characterise the subsets of $R^d$ with non-decreasing indicator function?

Tags: analysis

I am looking to characterise the subsets of $R^d$ for which the indicator function is non decreasing.

For example, if $d=1$, then I think that the subsets of $R$ with non-decreasing indicator function are of the form $(r, \infty)$ or $[r, \infty)$ for $r \in R$.

My question is, can this characterisation be generalised to $R^d$ where a function is nondecreasing if it is nondecreasing for all of it's elements.

i.e. $\forall i, \epsilon > 0$ $f(x_1,..., x_i + \epsilon, ... x_d ) \geq f(x_1,..., x_i, ... x_d )$.

Comment: Ah, you mean given some $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, the map $t\mapsto I_A(t)$ is monotone increasing (but not strictly)?

For this, you need an order on $\mathbb{R}^d$.  Which one did you have in mind?

Comment: Well, to define what "non-decreasing" means in $\mathbb R^d$, you would have to first define an order on the space. Depending on the order, you will have different results.

Comment: @Numbra , added the ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transitive, reflexive closure of your relation defines the following order: for any two points $x=(x_1, \dots, x_d),\; y=(y_1, \dots, y_d) \in \mathbb R^d$,
$$x \leq y \Leftrightarrow \forall 1 \leq i \leq d,\; x_i \leq y_i $$

Hence, it is not too hard to see that for any subset $A \subseteq \mathbb R^d$, the indicator function $\chi_A$ is non-decreasing if and only $A$ is a axis-parallel polytope of the form $(r_1, +\infty) \times \dots \times (r_d, +\infty)$, each of those being potentially closed interval, with $r_i \in \mathbb R \cup \{-\infty\}$

This is because as soon as you have a point $r=(r_1, \dots, r_d) \in A$, your order imposes that all the polytope of which $r$ is the "smallest corner" is included in $A$.

In dimension 2, this would just mean that if $r \in A$, then all the points above and on the right of it are also in $A$. By extension, you get this whole quarter of the plane.